# Spring 3 MVC: Data not display

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm dealing with a problem for some days, this is my problem:

I have some JSP page

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="saveNotaAbono">
```

I have this, for example:

```
<form:input path="factura.documentoBusqueda" id="facturaBusqueda"/>
```

And I put and object "factura" inside the ModelAndView, after that I'm pretty sure to fill the data "factura.documentoBusqueda" before return to the view.

Inside the JSP if I put:

```
${factura.documentoBusqueda}
```

I can SEE the data that I waiting.

But If I BIND the data with:

```
<form:input path="factura.documentoBusqueda" id="facturaBusqueda"/>
```

I cannot see it.

This is the header of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/storedevrecord/detalle/saveNotaDevolucion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveNotaDevolucion( @ModelAttribute("factura") FormularioDev form, HttpSession session) {
```

This is the toStirng of factura just before return ModelAndView.

I'm just triying to display "drDoc=3930", but I will go in madness

```
FormularioDev [operacion=null, rec=TDevRec [id=TDevRecPK [drCorrelativo=0, drCor=1, drPai=1, drCia=1, drSuc=3, drDoc=3930, drFechaVta=null, drCtgCodigo=null], drCddCli=null, drCelCli=null, drCtaCcr=null, drDevInt=null, drDireccCli=null, drDptoCli=null, drFecCrea=null, drFecInsMerc=null, drFecRec=null, drFecRecMerc=null, drIdcustomer=null, drNombreCli=null, drNotaAbono=null, drNumdocCli=null, drPagoReem=null, drPerApr=null, drPerInsMerc=null, drPerRecMerc=null, drPrima=null, drRecDevApl=null, drSucDev=null, drTelCli=null, drTotalCre=null, drTotalVta=null, drUbicMerc=null, drUsrCrea=null, drValPendLet=null, drValorPend=null, TCatTipGe=null, TDevRecDetas=null, TDevRecFpags=null, TDevRevMovs=null], formasPago=[MetaTPstpag [selected=false, pago=Pstpag [pstpagPK=com.siman.jpa.model.posdbcorp.PstpagPK[ cortpg=1, paitpg=1, ciatpg=1, suctpg=3, codtpg=7 ], nomtpg=CREDISIMAN, abrtpg=jdisji, ctctpg=ola, ctatpg=3]]], detalle=[TDevRecDeta [id=null, drdCandet=0, drdCantArt=null, drdCodVndr=0, drdDivdet=null, drdSku=100001011, drrDesk=null, drrIva=0.13, drrMnrdet=null, drrMordet=null, drrMotdet=null, drrPorDesc=null, drrPrecioTotal=null, drrPredet=null, TDevRec=null, TMotDevItem=null], TDevRecDeta [id=null, drdCandet=0, drdCantArt=null, drdCodVndr=0, drdDivdet=null, drdSku=413207900008, drrDesk=null, drrIva=0.13, drrMnrdet=null, drrMordet=null, drrMotdet=null, drrPorDesc=null, drrPrecioTotal=null, drrPredet=null, TDevRec=null, TMotDevItem=null], TDevRecDeta [id=null, drdCandet=0, drdCantArt=null, drdCodVndr=0, drdDivdet=null, drdSku=438126700027, drrDesk=null, drrIva=0.13, drrMnrdet=null, drrMordet=null, drrMotdet=null, drrPorDesc=null, drrPrecioTotal=null, drrPredet=null, TDevRec=null, TMotDevItem=null]], enca=null, newDeta=null, documentoBusqueda=null]
```

I will pretty aprecciate the help.

Regards.

Comment: It will help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668868/pre-populated-forminput-field-spring-form-tld-tag-library

Answer (score 2):

Change your jsp page to:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="saveNotaAbono" commandName="factura">
    <form:input path="documentoBusqueda" />
</form:form>
```

The `commandName` (or `modelAttribute`) attribute of `<form:form>` specify the exposed form object. The `path` attribute of `<form:input>` specify the form object property for data binding.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , but It still not working :/ this is "factura" Of type Formulariodev just before return ModelAndView

Comment: If ${factura.documentoBusqueda} have a value I think that is should works! Are you sure that you have write form:form and not only form?

Comment: Pretty sure <form:form id="form1" method="post" action="saveNotaDevolucion" commandName="factura">